# MS Access Export via ODBC to Specific DB2 Schema

Tags: ms-access, odbc, db2

I am trying to export a table from MS Access (2007) to DB2 (9.7 LUW) using ODBC.  I can do this, as long as I export the table into my own schema.

However, I would like to export the table to another schema.  How can I get Access to put the table into another schema?  In Db2, the table `foo` within schema `bar` is normally referred to as `bar.foo`.  However, if I enter this as the target to export to, Access gives me an error:

*The object name 'bar.foo' you entered doesn't follow Microsoft Access object-naming rules.*

This is because it won't accept a period in the table name.  Does anyone know how I can overcome this limitation?  I can just copy the table over after the export, but some other users don't have permission to create tables in their own schema; thus, this is preventing them from exporting from Access.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried a passthrough query?

Comment: @Remou, thanks for the suggestion.  I looked into pass-throughs, and I can send a command to the DB2 server easily enough.  But how would I refer to the local table stored in Access?  i.e. in order to export, I would need to do something like: `insert into table_on_db2 select * from table_on_access`. As I understand it, the pass-through query is simply sent directly to DB2, so it can't select from the table that is in the Access database.

Comment: oops, silly suggestion, sry. I have just test an MS Access query against SQL Server, and it is accepting `dbo.Table1`, so how are you running your export? Can you link DB2 tables to MS Access?

Comment: Select the "External Data" tab, then go to Export->More->ODBC Database.  A dialog pops up saying "Export table to:".  I try to enter schema.table, but it gives me the error at that point.

Comment: I am not at all familiar with DB2, but I know what I would do if I were to try this with SQL Server, do you want to try that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15571/discussion-between-remou-and-dan1111)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remou suggested using a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
INTO [ODBC;<db2 connection string>].schema.table
FROM ms_access_table1
```

I believe something similar could be made to work for DB2.  I suggest trying this if anyone needs a solution.  I have decided to stick with my current kludgy approach, however.  It is a shame that Access's export feature can't do this for such a dumb reason.